# Lua I/O dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, lua

I'm a Lua novice.  I'm unit testing Lua 5.1 code using [Lunity](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-11/msg00423.html) and [LeMock](http://lemock.luaforge.net/userguide.html).

My class is StorageManager.  I'm unit testing its load() method, which loads files from disk.  I don't want my unit tests dependent on actual files on the actual disk to test that.

So, I'm trying to inject the I/O dependency with a mock object and verify that object's behavior during my test.  I can't figure out how to use the I/O object with a syntax that works when called by both my mock-based unit test and the "real code".

How can I change the code (the load() method, preferably) so that it will do its job when called from either unit test (the one without the mock is temporary until I get this figured out -- it resembles the code that will later actually call the method under test)?

Note1: If you run these tests, remember that the "without mock" test expects a file on disk whose filename matches VALID_FILENAME.

Note2: I thought about using pcall's try/catch-like behavior to execute one line or the other (see storageManager.lua lines 11 & 12).  Assuming that's even possible, it feels like a hack, and it traps errors I might later want thrown (out of load()).  Please expound on this option if you see no alternative.

**test_storageManager.lua:**

```
 1 require "StorageManager"
 2 require "lunity"
 3 require "lemock"
 4 module("storageManager", package.seeall, lunity)
 5 
 6 VALID_FILENAME = "storageManagerTest.dat"
 7 
 8 function setup()
 9     mc = lemock.controller()
10 end
11 
12 function test_load_reads_file_properly()
13     io_mock = mc:mock()
14     file_handle_mock = mc:mock()
15     io_mock:open(VALID_FILENAME, "r");mc:returns(file_handle_mock)
16     file_handle_mock:read("*all")
17     file_handle_mock:close()
18     mc:replay()
19     storageManager = StorageManager:new{ io = io_mock }
20     storageManager:load(VALID_FILENAME)
21     mc:verify()
22 end
23 
24 function test_load_reads_file_properly_without_mock()
25     storageManager = StorageManager:new()
26     storageManager:load(VALID_FILENAME)
27 end
28 
29 runTests{useANSI = false}
```

**storageManager.lua:**

```
 1 StorageManager = {}
 2 
 3 function StorageManager.new (self,init)
 4     init = init or { io=io } -- I/O dependency injection attempt
 5     setmetatable(init,self)
 6     self.__index = self
 7     return init
 8 end
 9 
10 function StorageManager:load(filename)
11     file_handle = self['io'].open(self['io'], filename, "r") -- works w/ mock
12     -- file_handle = io.open(filename, "r") -- works w/o mock
13     result = file_handle:read("*all")
14     file_handle:close()
15     return result
16 end
```

**Edit:**

These classes pass both tests.  Many thanks to the RBerteig.

**test_storageManager.lua**

```
 1 require "admin.StorageManager"
 2 require "tests.lunity"
 3 require "lib.lemock"
 4 module("storageManager", package.seeall, lunity)
 5 
 6 VALID_FILENAME = "storageManagerTest.dat"
 7 
 8 function setup()
 9     mc = lemock.controller()
10 end
11
12 function test_load_reads_file_properly()
13     io_mock = mc:mock()
14     file_handle_mock = mc:mock()
15     io_mock.open(VALID_FILENAME, "r");mc:returns(file_handle_mock)
16     file_handle_mock:read("*all")
17     file_handle_mock:close()
18     mc:replay()
19     local saved_io = _G.io
20     _G.io = io_mock
21     package.loaded.io = io_mock
22     storageManager = StorageManager:new()
23     storageManager:load(VALID_FILENAME)
24     _G.io = saved_io
25     package.loaded.io = saved_io
26     mc:verify()
27 end
28
29 function test_load_reads_file_properly_without_mock()
30     storageManager = StorageManager:new()
31     storageManager:load(VALID_FILENAME)
32 end
33
34 runTests{useANSI = false}
```

**storageManager.lua**

```
 1 StorageManager = {}
 2 
 3 function StorageManager.new (self,init)
 4     init = init or {}
 5     setmetatable(init,self)
 6     self.__index = self
 7     return init
 8 end
 9 
10 function StorageManager:load(filename)
11     file_handle = io.open(filename, "r")
12     result = file_handle:read("*all")
13     file_handle:close()
14     return result
15 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are making the problem more difficult than it has to be.

Assuming that the module storageManager.lua is not itself localizing the `io` module, then all you need to do is to replace the global `io` with your mock object while running the test.

If the module does localize the `io` object for performance, then you would need to inject the new value of `io` before loading the module. This might mean that you need to make the call to `require` part of the test case setup (and a matching cleanup that removes all traces of the module from `package.loaded` and `_G`) so that it can be mocked differently in different test cases.
WinImage

**Edit:**

By localizing a module for performance I mean the Lua idiom of copying the module's methods into local variables in the module's name space. For example:

```
-- somemodule.lua
require "io"
require "math"

-- copy io and math to local variables
local io,math=io,math

-- begin the module itself, note that package.seeall is not used so globals are
-- not visible after this point
module(...)

function doMathAndIo()
    -- does something interesting here
end
```

If you do this, the references to the stock modules `io` and `math` are made at the moment that `require "somemodule"` is executed. Replacing either of those modules after the call to `require()` with a mocked version will not be effective.

To effectively mock a module that is used with this idiom, you would have to have the mock object in place *before* the call to `require()`.

Here is a how I would go about replacing the io object for the duration of the call in a test case:

```
function test_load_reads_file_properly()
    io_mock = mc:mock()
    file_handle_mock = mc:mock()
    io_mock:open(VALID_FILENAME, "r");mc:returns(file_handle_mock)
    file_handle_mock:read("*all")
    file_handle_mock:close()
    mc:replay()

    local saved_io = _G.io
    _G.io = io_mock
    package.loaded.io = io_mock
    storageManager = StorageManager:new{ }
    storageManager:load(VALID_FILENAME)
    _G.io = saved_io
    package.loaded.io = saved_io
    mc:verify()
end
```

I may not be restoring the real object at exactly the right moment, and this is untested, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't mean (or know how) to "localize the io object for performance", but I do want to "replace the global io with [my] mock object while running the test". I thought I was doing that on storageManager.lua:4? How does one properly "replace the global io"? Can you provide (or point me to) example code?

Comment: Your edit gave me what I needed.  I've edited my changed code into the original question.  Many thanks.